# Why has MySQL-python package been removed as part of the removal of MariaDB?

Tags: centos, python, yum, mysql, mariadb

Recently I removed some MariaDB packages in order to install a new version from an RPM file.

```
yum remove mariadb mariadb-server mariadb-libs
```

And as part of the process yum also removed MySQL-python package. Why did it do this? I searched online to see which MariaDB package has MySQL-python as a dependency but could not locate this information clearly.

```
 Command Line   : remove mariadb mariadb-server mariadb-libs
Transaction performed with:
    Installed     rpm-4.11.3-25.el7.x86_64                      @base
    Installed     yum-3.4.3-154.el7.centos.1.noarch             @updates
    Installed     yum-plugin-fastestmirror-1.1.31-42.el7.noarch @base
Packages Altered:
    Erase MySQL-python-1.2.5-1.el7.x86_64      @G****
    Erase mariadb-1:5.5.56-2.el7.x86_64        @base
    Erase mariadb-libs-1:5.5.56-2.el7.x86_64   @base
    Erase mariadb-server-1:5.5.56-2.el7.x86_64 @base
    Erase net-snmp-1:5.7.2-28.el7_4.1.x86_64   @G*****
    Erase perl-DBD-MySQL-4.023-5.el7.x86_64    @base
```

I did reinstall the MySQL-python package but when installing with yum, it says it has no dependencies.

Comment: The `MySQL-python` package probably has `mariadb` as dependency.

Comment: Did you have MySQL installed?

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that `MySQL-python` (and `perl-DBD-MySQL`) has MariaDB client libraries as dependencies. These packages are useless (unusable) without MySQL/MariaDB client libraries.

I can't test this, but installing `MySQL-python` again would probably at least reinstall `mariadb-libs`.

Comment: I actually did re-install MySQL-python package and it has no dependencies. I will update my question with this information.

Comment: @MattB I wonder... Do you have _another_ MySQL client library package installed?